# Минимизация количества merge коммитов

Tags: git, git-merge

Я предпочитаю не использовать merge при работе с git, вместо него обычно использую rebase. Поэтому история рабочих веток у меня обычно представляет собой дерево. Но иногда без merge не обойтись, поэтому возник такой вопрос.
Предположим, у меня есть две независимые ветки feature1 и feature2, а также ветка feature3, которая зависит от них обеих:

```
o---o---o master
 \
  ---o---o---o-------o feature1
  \                   \
   ---o---o feature2   \
           \            \
            -------------M---A---B feature3
```

Далее я изменяю ветку feature1, добавив туда коммит F:

```
o---o---o master
 \
  ---o---o---o-------o-----------F feature1
  \                   \
   ---o---o feature2   \
           \            \
            -------------M---A---B feature3
```

Теперь я хочу, чтобы эти изменения попали в ветку feature3. Обычно в таких случаях делают merge feature1 в feature3 и получают историю вроде такой:

```
o---o---o master
 \
  ---o---o---o-------o-----------F feature1
  \                   \           \
   ---o---o feature2   \           \
           \            \           \
            -------------M---A---B---m feature3
```

Мне же хочется, чтобы история изменений была как можно более простой. Для этого можно создать новый merge коммит feature1 и feature2 (назовем его M') и накатить коммиты A и B поверх него, тем самым получив тот же результат, что и при merge. История при этом будет иметь всего один merge коммит:

```
o---o---o master
 \
  ---o---o---o---o---F feature1
  \                   \
   ---o---o feature2   \
           \            \
            -------------M'---A'---B' feature3
```

Собственно, вопрос: есть ли способ добиться такого эффекта одной-двумя коммандами? Самое простое, до чего я додумался, это:

```
git checkout -b tmp feature1
git merge feature2
git rebase M --onto tmp feature3
git branch -D tmp
```

но такой способ мне не очень нравится, т.к. требует слишком много ручных действий.

Comment: Как вы такие красивые древовидные структуры рисуете, руками?

Answer (score 1):

Вам просто нужно сделать:

```
git checkout feature3
git rebase feature1
```